# How to write the criteria query for NVL in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have column c in Table A and Table B,How do i write criteria query for a where clause:

select * from A a,B b where A.c=NVL(B.c,'Constant');

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NVL` function behaves similarly to `COALESCE`, the latter which is natively supported by Hibernate query language.  So, you may use `COALESCE` instead:

```
select * from A a, B b where A.c = COALESCE(B.c, 'Constant');
```